# retrieving parameter from function

Tags: c#

I have 2 functions, one that gets a name and the other that is being set up to Delete from the list of name. There are no compliation errors, but my DeleteName doesn't display anything. Probally a simple fix, what did I overlook?

```
    public static List<string> GetName(List<string> aString)
    {
        aString = new List<string>();
        localList.Add("cat");
        localList.Add("apple");
        localList.Add("bass");
        localList.Add("dog");
      return aString;
    }
    public static List<string> DeleteName(List<string> aString)
    {
        aString = new List<string>();
        GetName(aString);
        foreach (string x in aString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        return aString;
    }
```

Comment: I'm very sure that this code does not compile without errors. localList is not defined.

Comment: Hmmm why are you creating aString at DeleteName function? you are actually receiving that as a list...

Comment: Is that your full DeleteName method?  It doesn't really do what the name says it does?

Comment: this whole court is out of order!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems odd that you are passing the List and then returning it as well.  Try changing your code to this:

```
public static List<string> GetName()
{
    List<string> aString = new List<string>();
    aString.Add("cat");
    aString.Add("apple");
    aString.Add("bass");
    aString.Add("dog");
  return aString;
}
public static List<string> DeleteName()
{
    List<string>  aString = GetName();
    foreach (string x in aString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    return aString;
}
```

As @hunter points out you could do this without declaring your list in `GetName`.  Code:

```
    public static void GetName(List<string> aString)
    {
        aString.Add("cat");
        aString.Add("apple");
        aString.Add("bass");
        aString.Add("dog");
    }
    public static List<string> DeleteName()
    {
        List<string> aString = new List<string>();
        GetName(aString);
        foreach (string x in aString)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
        return aString;
    }
```

Also, as @Dustin Laine pointed out but then deleted, you will get the same result if you do not set `aString` to a new object in `GetName()`.  Code:

```
public static List<string> GetName(List<string> aString)
{
    //aString = new List<string>();
    aString.Add("cat");
    aString.Add("apple");
    aString.Add("bass");
    aString.Add("dog");
    return aString;
}
public static List<string> DeleteName(List<string> aString)
{
    aString = new List<string>();
    GetName(aString);
    foreach (string x in aString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    return aString;
}
```

This still seems like a very strange way to write your code and I would not recommend it.

Comment: why declare `aString` in `GetName()` at all?

Comment: This will compile without errors, but the console will still not display anything.

Comment: @jpavlov, have you tested this?  Both of my examples above display what you would expect.

Comment: @hunter, I guess you don't have to.  Do you know if the second version will be more efficient?

Comment: @Abe I think that's more what the OP is going for but I would just make `GetName()` return a list with no parameters and `aString` in `DeleteName` would just be set to the result of `GetName()`

Comment: Hmmm, what list would it return if you don't pass GetName any params and you don't declare a list within the function?

Comment: @Abe I agree, it doesn't make a whole lot of sense. From the OPs question is looks like everything is declared within `GetName()` anyway. I think OP is just trying to figure out how things work.

Answer (score 5):

You're passing `aString` to `GetName` but not doing anything with the resulting `List`. **In `GetName()` there seems to be no reason to pass in `aString` since you're setting it to a new instance.** You're also not doing anything with the `aString` passing to `DeleteName`. If you wanted to combine the first collection with the second you could try something like this:

```
public static List<string> GetName(List<string> aString)
{
    List<string> localList= new List<string>(aString);

    localList.Add("cat");
    localList.Add("apple");
    localList.Add("bass");
    localList.Add("dog");

    return localList;
}

public static List<string> DeleteName(List<string> aString)
{
    aString = GetName(aString);
    foreach (string x in aString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    return aString;
}
```

Comment: What would be the benefit of passing `aString` here?

Comment: Depends what the OP is trying to do, but I'm guessing OP is just testing things out

Answer (score 3):

Changing it to

```
public static List<string> GetName(ref List<string> aString)
```

should fix it. `aString` in `GetName` is a pointer to the list created in `DeleteName`. On line 3 of that method, you are setting `aString` to point to a different location, and then working with that location. You then return it, but don't use it. This leaves the list created in `DeleteName` unchanged. Another possible fix since you do return the list is to change `DeleteName`'s call to be

```
aString = GetName(null);
```

But that's weird as well, since the list is never actually used in `GetName`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to make them `ref` parameters? If you don't want that, it would be `aString = GetName(aString)` instead of `GetName(aString)` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

because you are writing the foreach result.
You probably will do:

```
    foreach(string x in aString)
{
      astring.Add(x);
}
Console.WriteLine(aString);

// or 

return aString;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the result of aString. You should do something like aString = GetName(aString).

There are a lot of other things wrong with this code as posted, though.